# Change pub.dev location

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I formatted my windows drive and reinstalled windows. But before that I copied C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Pub to E:/Pub because I don't wanna loose my pub.dev content.
In my new windows I don't want to take pub.dev back to it's original place. I want it to live in E:/Pub So I searched and the document says I should use the following before "flutter pub get":

```
PUB_CACHE E:\Pub\Cache
```

But I don't want to repeat this for every project.

So how can I apply this to all of my existing and next projects to ensure all of them are using one directory to download/import dependencies.

Comment: `PUB_CACHE` is an environment variable.  You can simply edit your system's environment variables to apply it globally.  To set environment variables on Windows, see https://superuser.com/q/284342/.

Comment: Sorry , Thanks